# Unmet dependencies - cannot remove package libgbm1

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, ppa, dependencies

In this case I have the `libgbm1` being held, giving me message like:

```
Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Since I carefully read [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) I tried to remove the broken package with `sudo apt-get remove libgbm1` as suggested. However, remove command gave me the same error.

`sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't upgrade this package (`"...and 1 not upgraded."`). And I need this one to build some other packages that depends on it (`pkgProblemResover` problem again). It seems I cannot revert the version nor move forward.

Steps I've ever tried:

- disabling some ppa repositories in `software updates` and `sudo apt-get update` then tried to fix with apt, which didn't work.
- `sudo apt-get -f install` with `and 1 not upgraded`.
- tried to install packages that `libgbm1` depends on. But more packages coming forward and quickly piles up to tens of them, which seems unreliable to handle, and they also reported similar errors.

Why couldn't I remove the package? How to fix it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem here is to lock down the trouble maker package and kick it out. Then you can fix inconsistent dependencies with `sudo apt-get -f install`

So with cautious you may use: `sudo dpkg --force-all -P libgbm1` to force removing the broken. This command may damage your system, so you should watch it. And try to fix: `sudo apt-get -f install`.

If any packages are corrupting as well, repeat above steps cautiously. And each time you removed broken packages, try to fix them. I tackled my problem in this case.

Comment: Thank you, two days of pain before to find your answer! However I have to complete your answer because I had to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` after `sudo dpkg --force-all -P libgbm1` to finish the install

Comment: Thank you `sudo dpkg --force-all -P <package>` was the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of rushing to remove your broken packages using the `--force-all` option of `dpkg`, first try removing it without this option, using simply

```
dpkg -P package-name
```

In my case, `dpkg` printed why it couldn't remove this package: another package depended on it. After I removed the dependee, the broken package could finally be removed, without any `--force-anything`.

This may require several recursive removals in case when the dependee is also broken, but the end result should be fixing the dependency chain, which `apt` was unable to fix, by removals.

Comment: This was the only solution I could find that worked to help me with my problem, unable to install because of unmet dependencies

Comment: You can delete the dependencies of dependencies recursively as well!

Answer (score 3):

**Force Reconfigure or Remove Broken Packages with DPKG**

Reconfigure DPKG, the base package management system, with the following command:

**`sudo dpkg --configure -a`**

Check if DPKG marked some packages as needing a reinstall.

**`sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..R`**

If the command above returns a list of one or more packages, try removing the packages by typing:

**`sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libgbm1`**

After you finish troubleshooting, run the following command to clean up the system:

**`sudo apt clean`**

Then update the repositories:

**`sudo apt update`**

Then upgrade the repositories:

**`sudo apt upgrade`**

Hope it helps.